# Error Formatting Query, probably Invalid Parameter

Tags: sql-server

I created a SQL mail job on Thursday and it runs hourly.  It ran fine until Sunday at 3 for which it has been failing with the following error.

> Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. Error formatting query,
>   probably invalid parameters [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 22050)  Query
>   execution failed: Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Server PRxxxxxxx3\Xxxx,
>   Line 1  The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'MFGITMTRK',
>   database 'xxxx', schema 'LIVE'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 14661).  The
>   step failed.

Here is the proc I am running via SSIS.  It runs fine manually in SSMS and in VS so it appears to be some kind of permissions issue. Not sure why it would start all of a sudden.

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Dup_WO_Tracking_email]
  AS

  DECLARE             @recordcount INT

  SELECT @recordcount = ISNULL(COUNT(*),0) 


  FROM LIVE.MFGITMTRK
  WHERE CREDAT_0 >='2019-11-08 00:00:00.000'
  AND CREUSR_0='GE002'
  GROUP BY MFGNUM_0,CREDAT_0
  HAVING COUNT(MFGNUM_0)>1


  IF (@recordcount > 0)

  BEGIN

  EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
  @profile_name = 'SQL Mail',
  @recipients = 'xxx.xxxxx@cxxx.com;xxx.xxxxx@cxxx.com

   ;xxx.xxxxx@cxxx.com;Bill.xxx.xxxxx@cxxx.com
              ;xxx.xxxxx@cxxx.com'

      ,
      @query = 'Select MFGNUM_0 FROM [PRODYCHDBX3\X3V7].[x3v7].[LIVE]. 
       [MFGITMTRK]
            WHERE CREDAT_0 >="2019-11-08 00:00:00.000"
            AND CREUSR_0="GE002"
            GROUP BY MFGNUM_0,CREDAT_0
            HAVING COUNT(MFGNUM_0)>1',

     @subject = ' Duplicate Work Order Production Tracking',
--@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
  @body =0,
  @execute_query_database ='xxxx' ;
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

I have change permissions in sql mail from extended to verbose.

Comment: You may want to remove actual emails from your post.

Comment: Since nothing changed in your code, I presume, then something MUST have changed in your database where access was revoked. This may be better asked in dba.stackexchange.com since it's probably not a result of programming.

Comment: `The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'MFGITMTRK'` Maybe you change some permissions